# Why does this cause an infinite while loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm completely new to coding and have started learning JavaScript recently. I don't understand why the following code causes an infinite loop. Why does the `birthday(myAge)` function not work within the loop to make the condition `(myAge < 23)` false?

```
var myAge = 22
var birthday = function(myAge){
    return(myAge + 1);
}

while (myAge < 23){
    console.log("You're only 22");
    birthday(myAge)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are not modifying `myAge` in any way. Your function is simply returning `myAge + 1`.

Try assigning the return value back to `myAge`:

```
while (myAge < 23){
    console.log("You're only 22");
    myAge = birthday(myAge);
}
```

Or alternatively, if you remove the function parameter, then the name `myAge` within the function will refer to the global variable, and you can modify it directly:

```
var myAge = 22
var birthday = function(){
    return (myAge = myAge + 1); 
    // or return myAge += 1;
    // or return ++myAge;
}

while (myAge < 23){
    console.log("You're only 22");
    birthday();        // note, no need to pass any parameters
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks that makes sense. But I don't understand why the 'birthday' function doesn't assign the value back to'myAge'?

Comment: @JosephByrne for a couple of reasons. 1) `myAge + 1` doesn't assign any values. It gets the current value and returns that value + 1. 2) The function parameter is different from the global variable, so simply modifying the parameter won't have any effect.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to write a function that does actually modify the variable's value? Or am I just misunderstanding what functions are for?

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I know this is pretty basic stuff!

Comment: @JosephByrne See my updated answer for an alternative

Comment: Oooh I like that - that's what I wanted to do. I get it now - while I had a function parameter I would only be able to modify that value, but if you remove it the function modifies the global variable.  thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to increment myAge in some way, or else you will be 22 forever... although that's not such a bad thing.  I think you discovered the fountain of youth.

```
return (myAge += 1)
```

Comment: Putting that inside the function will only modify the local variable (the parameter value), not the global variable.

Comment: myAge is a global variable already and not bound to the function scope.

Comment: Look again. In OP's code, there is a parameter named `myAge`, too. So `myAge += 1` will only modify the value of that parameter. You'd either have to assign the return value back to `myAge` outside of the function, or remove the parameter so `myAge` is bound to the global variable.

Comment: Correct, oversight on my part